# How to list all arguments a function in python module takes

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find how to list all the valid arguments a function in a python module can take.
For example the run method in subprocess module has different arguments in different versions, who do I list them ?

Example: text=True works in some versions while universal_newlines=True works in others, how do i find out which arguments are supported in each method without using interactive consoles like pycharm?

Comment: Check `help(thing)`? You can also see the versioning notes in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run): *"Changed in version 3.7: Added the text parameter, as a more understandable alias of universal_newlines. Added the capture_output parameter."*

Comment: It sees looking into the docs is the only way for now. Thanks for the inputs.